# no plug-and-play solution for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plug-and-play

Using standard UBUNTU 16 LTS env.   and used [enterprisedb.com/downloads PostgreSQL Setup Wizard](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads#linux) to install, an ["official suggestion" here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu)... So supposing it is plug-and-play.

But the basic (for a "plug and play") not runs (!), `psql -h localhost -U postgres`

> psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
>   FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

---

The user `postgres` exist, and even after `sudo passwd postgres`  to "postgres", the same error.

Comment: `sudo passwd postgres` changes OS user password, not db... `alter user postgres password'blah'` is for db

Comment: what you see after `sudo su - postgres` and then `psql` with no arguments?..

Comment: Thanks @VaoTsun. Yes...  But during installation I say "postgres postgres" ... To do "all by terminal again" is not a plug-in-play... it is ugly. I am looking for what is wrong in my concept of plug-in-play... I think it is a bug to be reported in case there are no real solution.